# Customising Image size and padding in Squarespace

Tags: html, css, image, squarespace

I've had the misfortune of inheriting the task to update my company's website with our newest members. Due to this being a small company, the previous guy did not leave any documentation or notes based on how he created the website.

Essentially right now we have a members page that contains Image Blocks (Inline, with captions). [Click here](https://ctpartners.com.au/members) to get to the page in question.

I'm trying to add a new member in, but it seems like the previous guys has had some sort of customisation. Adding a new image block immediately showed to me that the current blocks are very different to the default ones that squarespace has. [See here](https://ctpartners.com.au/member-profile-1) for a staging page I created, with the newest image block (Simon McLean) on the very bottom right.

Took me hours to figure out that Squarespace actually resizes your images upon import to an image block. So I inspected the elements on Chrome and found the below elements to change. Below are screenshots from before the change to the elements to after the change in the elements:

Before: 
[image: Before Element Changes]

After: 
[image: After Element Changes]

Note that I got the changes by simply looking up the image next to the one used in the example (i.e. Example is Anna's Image and I'm trying to fix Simon's image).

Pardon the noob question, but how do I make these changes permanent? I've so far tried the following:

1. Modified the Custom CSS via the Design > Custom CSS using the below code. No discernible effect.

```
element.style {
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

2. Used the above code, but this time as a Page header injection. Still no effect.

I'm honestly out of ideas - Thank you for helping me. I'm definitely out of my depth here.

Comment: Having looked over your question and the page, I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve, but I do believe you may have a misunderstanding of Squarespace's image resizing. To start getting a better idea of the problem: Are you trying to add an additional image block or are you trying to edit an existing one? Have you successfully dragged-and-dropped a new image block into the grid (see: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/216576457-Creating-columns-and-rows-with-blocks )? I'm not clear what you mean by "make these changes permanent".

Comment: Ah - I suppose I'm not clear on that. I'm trying to add an additional image block, but make it uniform to the rest of the ones that already exist within that page.

The problem lies when I add the new image block to the existing grid - that image block uses the default for squarespace's template. Here's a staging page for comparison. The new image block in question is Simon's one at the very bottom of the page. 
https://ctpartners.com.au/member-profile-1

I tried looking at how to 'resize' the image using the Developer tools on Chrome, and  the image resizes itself once I refresh.

Comment: I took a look at the page where you added "Simon McLean" and I don't see any difference in that entry compare to all the other entries code wise. But, I did notice that "Simon McLean" Profile picture was 500x500 instead of 240x240 like the rest of the entries. Have you tried uploading a 240x240 image to "Simon McLean " and seeing if that was the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. The custom doesn't work cause of the CSS selector. Basically "element.style" should be something like
"#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1586830274979_24199 image"
(the id of the element followed by element your trying to add CSS too) so you can override the previous rules.

Comment: @QuentinGibson I've uploaded the 240x240 version of the same image but the issue still persists. Also, I've changed the CSS to add the below to the Page header injection:  
  
    <style>
      #block-yui_3_17_2_1_1587221501375_757 image {
    left: 0%; 
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>

Issue still persists too I'm afraid. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem you describe.

1) Resize the original image of Simon to the same size as the other original images (240x240) **before** you upload it. You may need to add a new, empty image block (instead of simply uploading the new image over the old one in the existing image block) because the old block may retain its undesirable settings/aspect ratio.

2) Use the "handle" at the bottom of the image to set it's height/aspect-ratio to your preference.

[image]

A third option would be use CSS and force the padding-bottom to the desired height/aspect-ratio, but that's hopefully unnecessary.

Note that the original images, being 240x240, will not appear sharp on high-resolution displays. Ideally, the images would have been uploaded at a much higher resolution, allowing Squarespace to determine the best resolution to deliver based on the display. Ideally, all such images would be reuploaded at some point.

Comment: I've changed the image and added the 240x240 version on the test page, but still have the same problem I'm afraid. I think there's some sort of CSS injection that's going on to add the padding so that Simon's image is the same as Anna's (based on the test page linked). 

Do you have any thoughts on the CSS injection I used above?

Comment: Can you share the page like you did on the question?

Comment: @Lazarius: Did you remove and re-add the block (not just replace the image) as mentioned in #1? Did you attempt to adjust the image height as in #2? Neither of those were addressed in your comment, so I wanted to clarify. Finally, the image on your example page is still 1000x1000, indicating it was not updated. Please follow step one on your example page, remove the block, add a new one, add the *250x250* image, use the lower handle to adjust as needed. Then report back after doing all those steps, verifying that the issue still exists on your example page you previously linked to.

Comment: My Apologies @Brandon Thank you so much for the clear instructions. Adding the photo to a new image block at 240x240 resizes it properly. Solution Verified.